# SQL filter elements of array

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table of employee similar to this:

```
Department   Data
A    [{"name":"John", "age":10, "job":"Manager"},{"name":"Eli", "age":40, "job":"Worker"},{"name":"Sam", "age":32, "job":"Manager"}]
B    [{"name":"Jack", "age":50, "job":"CEO"},{"name":"Mike", "age":334 "job":"CTO"},{"name":"Filip", "age":63, "job":"Worker"}]
```

I want to get the department, name, and age of all employees, something similar to this:

```
Department   Data
A    [{"name":"John", "age":10},{"name":"Eli", "age":40},{"name":"Sam", "age":32}]
B    [{"name":"Jack", "age":50},{"name":"Mike", "age":334},{"name":"Filip", "age":63}]
```

How can I achieve this using SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I assume you are using `Hive/Spark` and the datatype of the column is an array of maps.*

Using `explode` and `collect_list` and `map` functions.

```
select dept,collect_list(map("name",t.map_elem['name'],"age",t.map_elem['age'])) as res
from tbl 
lateral view explode(data) t as map_elem 
group by dept
```

Note that this would be not be as performant as a Spark solution or a UDF with which you can access the required keys in an `array` of `map`s, without a function like `explode`.

One more way to do this with Spark SQL functions [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#transform) and [`map_filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#map_filter) (only available starting Spark version 3.0.0).

```
spark.sql("select dept,transform(data, map_elem -> map_filter(map_elem, (k, v) -> k != \"job\")) as res from tbl")
```

Another option with Spark versions > 2.4 is using function [`element_at`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#element_at) with `transform` and selecting the required keys.

```
spark.sql("select dept," +
          "transform(data, map_elem -> map(\"name\",element_at(map_elem,\"name\"),\"age\",element_at(map_elem,\"age\"))) as res " +
          "from tbl")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd get your table into tabular format:
Department | Age | Job

Then:

```
SELECT Name, Age
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY Job
```